# Is there any decent way to bulk change a material Parameter?

Tags: materials, custom-attributes

I'm have imported a model of AnorLondo from Darksouls to Use as a lighting study. I have run into the problem of all the materials having a value of 1 for specularity. I have tried using the copy to selected and holding Alt while moving the slider. There are 63 different materials, all of which I would like to change the specularity value. I feel brute forcing it would do the trick, but would be very time consuming. Is there any quick/easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to *Scripting* workspace (tab), paste this code to Python console (and press <kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> twice) or to a new text block (and run it with ▶ Play button):

```py
from bpy import data as D
for mat in D.materials:
    if not mat.use_nodes: continue
    for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
        for inp in node.inputs:
            if inp.name == 'Specular':
                inp.default_value = 0.5
```

Notice the new value is at the very end, in general you should set specularity to $0.5$ for physically correct renders.